# Access Rake Task Description from within Task

Tags: ruby, rake

Within a rake task how does one query the description? Something that would give:

```
desc "Populate DB"
task populate: :environment do
  puts task.desc # "Populate DB"
end
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`task`must be defined as a parameter for the task-block.

```
desc "Populate DB"
task :populate do |task|
  puts task.comment # "Populate DB"
  puts task.full_comment # "Populate DB"
  puts task.name # "populate "
end
```

**Edit:** 
This solution works with rake 0.8.7. At least rake 0.9.2.2 need an additional `Rake::TaskManager.record_task_metadata = true` (I checked only this two versions).

A stand alone ruby-script with adaption:

```
gem 'rake'    #'= 0.9.2.2'
require 'rake'

#Needed for rake/gem '= 0.9.2.2'
Rake::TaskManager.record_task_metadata = true

desc "Populate DB"
task :populate do |task|
  p task.comment # "Populate DB"
  p task.full_comment # "Populate DB"
  p task.name # "populate "
end

if $0 == __FILE__
  Rake.application['populate'].invoke()  #all tasks
end
```

Reason: in `rake/task_manager.rb` line 30 (rake 0.9.2.2) is a check

```
  if Rake::TaskManager.record_task_metadata
    add_location(task)
    task.add_description(get_description(task))
  end
```

The default `false` is set in line 305.

Comment: `task.comment` appears to be returning `nil` for me. Any ideas?

Comment: The example works fine for me. Which version do you use? I have ruby 1.9.2 and  `RAKEVERSION = '0.8.7'`

Comment: I updated my rake to `0.9.2.2` - now I get `nil` for `task.comment` and `task.full_comment`.

Comment: I have 0.9.2.2 and using `task.name` works even without `Rake::TaskManager.record_task_metadata = true`, although maybe that's buried somewhere else in my environment (I'm working with someone else's codebase)

Comment: @KevinSylvestre:  I can confirm I had to add `Rake::TaskManager.record_task_metadata = true` to `config/application.rb`

Answer (score 3):

Having a similar problem, that I wanted to show the user a customized help screen. The answer here helped me a lot.

It is very important that

```
Rake::TaskManager.record_task_metadata = true
```

is done before the first definition of tasks.

Then you can do

```
Rake.application.tasks.each do |t|
    printf("%-}s  # %s\n",
           t.name_with_args,
           t.comment)
  end
```

Details can be found by investigating https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/application.rb#L284