# How to access namespace from within a rake task?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

My rake task (rake v 0.9.2.2) includes a bit to print out the name of the task. I'd like it to also print its namespace. Kind of like the following:

```
namespace :yelp do
    desc "..."
    task :scrape => :environment do
        puts "rake #{task.namespace}:#{task.name}"
    end
end
```

The problem is that `namespace` is a private method.

```
rake aborted!
private method `namespace' called for <Rake::Task  => []>:Rake::Task
```

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`task.name` includes the namespace. Use [this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8781522/1167833) to get `task.name` to print under rake 0.9.2.2.